# Алгоритмы оценок риска vs алгоритмы оценки риска

Tags: фразеология, склонение, словосочетания

Словосочетание "оценка риска" используется в моей области в двух значениях в зависимости от контекста:
1) Процесс оценивания риска
2) Количественный или качественный результат такого оценивания
В присылаемых в редакцию статьях часто можно встретить конструкции вида "алгоритмы оценок риска". При этом здесь речь идет именно о процессе, т.е. об алгоритме процедуры вычисления. 
Я всегда исправляю это на "алгоритмы оценки риска". 
Прав ли я?

Answer (score 1):

Грамматически тут проблем нет ни с одним из вариантов. "Алгоритмы" тут, полагаю, не самое важное. Вопрос в грамматической форме самого сочетания "оценка/оценки риска". А тут единства нет. Даже "оценка/оценки риск**ов**" встречается. При этом речь по сути идет об одном и том же, безотносительно к используемому грамматическому числу. Так что тут всего более надо ориентироваться на сложившуюся практику использования в той области, которую вы представляете.
Если речь идет о финансовой сфере, то там, насколько могу судить, устоявшийся термин - ***оценка рисков***. У военных - "оценки риска", вполне возможно, если речь идет о нескольких альтернативных оценках. В инженерном деле, как помню, - "оценки рисков". 
Короче, следуйте традициям своей области, но и чутьё авторов со счетов не сбрасывайте.

Наверное, можно сойтись на том, что если алгоритм на выходе дает одну оценку (это чаще всего), то "алгоритмы оценки". Иначе - алгоритмы оценок.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь более корректно - `алгоритмы оценки риска`. Это равно `алгоритмы оценивания (процесса - ед. ч.) риска`. Кроме того, этот вариант выдаёт гугл в результатах при поиске второго варианта.

Алгоритмы оценок - алгоритмы вычисления оценок. Звучит этот вариант не очень грамотно.

Также хорошо - алгоритм анализа рисков.